# Hide a fixed div with opacity 0.9 on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, opacity

in a recent template I have the title in a div i hide on scroll using this code:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".title").css("opacity", 0.9 - $(window).scrollTop() / 5);
  });
</script>
```

In Safari i have the issue that, if i scroll up in Safari through the div adds opacity that is higher than the standard value of 0.9. This does not look good on my template, because the div is part of a header with 0.9 opacity. I want it to maximal show with opacity 0.9, not 1 or 1.2 etc.

The effect is only visible in Safari through the scroll bounce effect. I tried adding this to my CSS without any positive effect:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Any ideas?

Ty, bye!

Answer (score 1):

You could check the value before you apply it and make sure it's not above 0.9 like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
   var opacity = 0.9 - $(window).scrollTop() / 5;
   if (opacity > 0.9)
   {
      opacity = 0.9;
   }
   $(".title").css("opacity", opacity);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional ternary to limit it:

```
var opacity = 0.9 - $(window).scrollTop() / 5;
$(".title").css("opacity", opacity > 0.9 ? 0.9 : opacity);
```